# Swift Firebase sending data inside a closure

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, swift2

I am trying to send data to another view controller. However, the data cannot be reached at the second view controller. Here is my code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)


    switch(segue.identifier ?? "") {

    case "tograddetail":
        print("Going to Grad Detail")


        guard let gradDetailViewController = segue.destination as? graduatedetailViewController else {
            fatalError("Unexpected destination: \(segue.destination)")
        }

        guard let selectedgradCell = sender as? GradTableViewCell else {
            fatalError("Unexpected sender: \(sender)")
        }

        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: selectedgradCell) else {
            fatalError("The selected cell is not being displayed by the table")
        }


        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Database")
        ref.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            //print(snapshot.value)
            if snapshot.exists() {
                if let countdowntime = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {

                    let selectedgrad = self.graduatename[indexPath.row]

                    if let graddata = countdowntime[selectedgrad] as? NSDictionary {

                        let theinstitution = graddata["Institution"] as! String
                        let thelocation = graddata["location"] as! String
                        let thetimeleft = graddata["timeleft"] as! Int

                        guard let firstgrad = graddetail(institution: theinstitution, location: thelocation, timeleft: thetimeleft) else {
                            fatalError("Unable to instantiate graddetail")
                        }
                        //print(firstgrad.institution)

                        //print(destinationgraddata.grad?.institution)



                        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! graduatedetailViewController
                        destinationVC.grad = firstgrad


                    }

                }
            }
        })

    default:
        fatalError("Unexpected Segue Identifier; \(segue.identifier)")
    }
}
```

And here is my code for the second view controller:

```
var grad: graddetail?

@IBOutlet weak var theinstitution: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let grad = grad {

        theinstitution.text = grad.institution

    }
}
```

However, the grad.institution value always return nil. Any idea?

Comment: Because `.observe` is async and segue will called sync so when you get response in completion block of it your segue is already performed

Comment: so how can I avoid this problem?

Comment: What you need to do is get value using `.observe` and inside the completion block of observe call the perfromSegue

Comment: Thanks! Problem Solved

Comment: yea sure! Go ahead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is `observe(_:with:)` is async and segue will called synchronously, so that when you get response in completion block of `observe` your segue is already performed.

To solved the issue what you need to do is call the `observe` before calling the `performSegue` and inside the completion block of `observe` when you get response call the `perfromSegue` with the value that you want to pass.